# What is the sum of the maximum and minimum values BC can take?

Tags: geometry

$\small AB$, $\small BD$ and $\small BC$ are are integer measurements
If $\small AB + BD = k$, find the maximum and minimum values that the $\small BC$ side can assume and then add the values found. (Answer: $k$)

My progress:

$\small \triangle ADB: |AB - BD |< AD < AB + BD \therefore \boxed{|AB-BD| < AD < k}\\$ $\small 
\triangle BCD: \boxed{|BD-DC| < BC < BD+DC}\\$ $\small
\boxed{\measuredangle B = 180^o -4\theta}\\$ $\small
\triangle ABC:\dfrac{AB}{\sin\theta}=\dfrac{BC}{\sin3\theta}\rightarrow \boxed{\dfrac{AB}{\sin\theta}=\dfrac{BC}{3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta}}\\\small \triangle BCD: \boxed{\frac{BC}{\sin 2\theta}=\frac{BD}{\sin\measuredangle C}}$

These are the relationships I found but I can't "see" how to get the answer.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are $A$ and $D$ fixed points?

Comment: @BrianTung +1, I also am confused.  **To the OP**: +1 to your question for work shown, embedding a clarifying diagram into the question, and for making a serious effort to explain the problem.  However, I agree with Brian Tung: it is unclear what you are asking.  Please proofread your question and try to edit it so that it is (ideally) absolutely impossible for anyone to be in any way confused about what you are asking.  Often, with a complicated question, such editing can be challenging.

Comment: Yes..A and D are fiexd points.. I  have two triangles..ABC e BCD, AB + BD = k.. I need find maiximum e minimum value that BC can assume. and then add the two values. The triangle sides are integer values

Comment: @useer2661923  Sorry, I tried to explain it better now..

Comment: There are two larger and three smaller triangles. Do you mean all sides of each are integers, or just the larger ones? Please specify.

Comment: @user2661923 The problem only mentions AB, BD and BC with integers. It's a peruvian problem.

Comment: B is on an ellipse with A and D as ellipse foci.

Comment: @user2661923 This problem follows the same idea, maybe help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200250/find-the-largest-and-smallest-values-of-the-angles-of-a-triangle?noredirect=1#comment8714595_4200250

Comment: @BrianTung  This problem follows the same idea, maybe help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200250/find-the-largest-and-smallest-values-of-the-angles-of-a-triangle?noredirect=1#comment8714595_4200250

Comment: @coffeemath The problem only mentions AB, BD and BC with integers. It's a peruvian problem.

Comment: Why the use of "sen" - do you mean the simple sine function? Your equation in the Rectangle does not seem right.

Comment: @Moti ..Why is it not correct? È the simple application of the sine theorem...

Comment: Because both BC and BD are above the line - the sine theorem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127732/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-moti).

Comment: I see you corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB=a, BD=b, BC=c$

$\triangle ABC: a\sin 3\theta=c\sin \theta \Rightarrow$
$a(3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta)=c\sin\theta\Rightarrow$
$a(3-4\sin^2\theta)=c\Rightarrow$
$\sin^2\theta=\frac{3a-c}{4a}\Rightarrow$
$c<3a$

$\triangle BCD: c\sin\angle BCD=b\sin 2\theta \Rightarrow$
$\sin\angle BCD=\frac{b}{c}\sin 2\theta$

$0 < \angle CBD < 180^\circ-4\theta$,
$\angle BCD=180^\circ-\angle CBD-2\theta\Rightarrow$
$2\theta < \angle BCD < 180^\circ-2\theta\Rightarrow$
$\sin\angle BCD > \sin 2\theta\Rightarrow c<b$

Any $c<{\rm min}(3a,b)$ is satisfying conditions.
Addition of positive integer requirements gives
$c_{min}=1$, $c_{max}=k-1$, $c_{min}+c_{max}=k$.

Comment: Excellent..GratefulL

Comment: Reviewing the question I had a doubt.. $csin\angle BCD = bsin 2\theta$..Would not be $csin\angle BCD = BDsin 2\theta$ and not  $bsin2\theta$ ?